# Importing .bak file into Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have received a .bak file that contains a database backup, and I need to import it into an Azure SQL Database. I have tried using the "Restore" feature in Azure portal, but it seems that Azure SQL Database does not support direct restore from a .bak file. I have reviewed other questions as well it says it can only import .bacpac file if anyone can help me converting from .bak to .bacpac.

I have also seen suggestions to use the Export/Import feature, but I'm not sure about the exact steps involved. Can someone guide me on how to import the data from the .bak file into my Azure SQL Database?

I would appreciate any help or pointers on how to accomplish this task. Thank you in advance!

I tried to import it in Azure SQL server import data tier app but when it is opening it says only support .bacpac file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot import **`.bak`** file directly in Azure SQL database. Import feature of Azure SQL database support `.bacpac` file.

The workaround you can try is as below:

1. You need to restore **`.bak`** file to  in your local **SSMS**

- Right click  **Databases**  on left pane (Object Explorer)
- Click  **Restore Database...**
- Choose  **Device**, click  ..., and add your  ***.bak***  file
- Click  **OK**, then  **OK**  again

[image]

2. Then again export this restored database to **`.bcpac`** file. like below:
   [image]
3. After this upload this .bacpac file to your storage account.
   [image]
4. Then use this storage account and file to import database. using Import feature in Azure SQL database.

Comment: Thank you so much, it partly helped me because when I tried to restore it in SSMS it was giving me error because I installed SQL server express version which has a limit of 10 gb. I upgraded my express to developer version from SQL server installation center and than followed the above procedure. Thanks again 